# Does copying and pasting an entire database of products result in effective SEO?

Tags: html, seo

I'm building a website for someone who has an inventory of over 25,000+ parts with very specific part numbers that are all stored within a MS SQL database.

So would it be a good idea to copy and paste the entire database and put it within the index.html homepage but use CSS to make it invisible?

After copying and pasting each item on the webpage like below, I would be set in CSS code to `display:none;` so the website visitors won't be able to see the ugly data about thousands of individual parts below but Google's search crawlers will:

```
FEDERAL STOCK NUM, SPECIFICATION NUM, NATIONAL STOCK NUMBER
federalstock1......specificationnum1...NSN1................
federalstock2......specificationnum2...NSN2................
federalstock3......specificationnum3...NSN3................
federalstock4......specificationnum4...NSN4................
federalstock5......specificationnum5...NSN5................
```

My whole idea here is each federal stock number, all 25,000 of them are completely unique and a Google search for a particular federal stock number will land you on a page of the competitor websites.

Is it a good idea to copy/paste this corporation's entire inventory but make it cosmetically invisible to visitors via but  CSS?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Crawlers tend to not index hidden content. They may actually penalize you.

Comment: This is called cloaking and is very bad for SEO. It means instant ban. Don't do it.

Comment: @JohnConde I thought cloaking was a term for serving _different_ content to the search engine and the user, this is the same content with the same visibility. Not that it probably helps ranking anyway...

Comment: If it is visible to search engines and not to users it is cloaking, too. After all, users and search engines see different things.

Comment: @JohnConde Ok, there probably are multiple definitions then, Google's seems file based and is *[Cloaking](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2008/06/how-google-defines-ip-delivery.html#Cloaking): Serving different content to users than to Googlebot. This is a violation of our webmaster guidelines. If the file that Googlebot sees is not identical to the file that a typical user sees, then you're in a high-risk category. A program such as md5sum or diff can compute a hash to verify that two different files are identical.*

Answer (score 1):

No, that's spam and won't rank. If you want your customer to rank for those stock numbers create a page for each product and add the number visibly to the page along with the product description, images and other product-related content

Answer (score 1):

No - it wont help you.  In fact, it may hurt you because the search engines see that you have hidden content - and a TON of it at that - and penalize you.

Plus, all of that added content is going to slow your page load times which may negatively impact your rank.